# Flutter:formkey.currentState!.reset() not clearing the data

Tags: flutter, validation, reset, flutter-getx, flutter-textformfield

I am trying to clear TextFormField data after validation and clear the validation errors.
I am using formkey.currentState.reset to clear the errors.
If I use formkey.currentState.reset errors are being cleared but the values in fields don't clear,and if I dont use formkey.currentState.reset fields are being cleared but errors remain unclear.
How can i fix it
Here is my form with text fields

**homeView.dart**

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            print("validated");
            controller.resetAll();
            formKey.currentState!.reset();
          }
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Form(
                key: formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Wrap(
                      spacing: 5,
                      children: [
                        CustomTextField(
                          textEditingController: controller.usernameController,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            // Handle onChanged event for username
                          },
                          hintText: 'Enter your username',
                          isEnabled: true,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          validateField: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty) {
                              return "required";
                            } else {
                              return null;
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 16),
                        CustomTextField(
                          textEditingController: controller.emailController,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            // Handle onChanged event for email
                          },
                          hintText: 'Enter your email',
                          isEnabled: true,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          validateField: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty) {
                              return "required";
                            } else {
                              return null;
                            }
                          },
                        ),
```

Following is homeController

**homeController.dart**

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {
 

 var name="".obs;
  late TextEditingController usernameController ;
  late TextEditingController emailController  ;
  late TextEditingController passwordController;
  late TextEditingController ageController;
  late TextEditingController phoneNumberController ;
 GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey();
 // getting data from api


  @override
  void onInit() {
    name.value="";
    usernameController =TextEditingController();
    emailController  =TextEditingController();
    passwordController=TextEditingController();
    ageController=TextEditingController();
    phoneNumberController =TextEditingController();
    formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    super.onInit();
  }
  resetAll(){
    usernameController.clear() ;
    emailController.clear()  ;
    passwordController.clear();
    ageController.clear();
    phoneNumberController.clear();
  }
}
```

Following is customTextField

**customTextField.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';


import '../../config/theme/my_styles.dart';
import '../../config/translations/strings_enum.dart';

class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomTextField(
      {Key? key,
        required this.textEditingController,
        this.onChanged,
        this.hintText,
        required this.isEnabled,
        this.keyboardType,
        this.inputFormatters,
        this.validateField
      })
      : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController textEditingController;
  final void Function(String)? onChanged;
  final String? hintText;
  final TextInputType? keyboardType;
  final String? Function(String?)? validateField;
  bool isEnabled = true;
  List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormatters;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Container(
      width: 150,
      child: TextFormField(
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        validator: validateField,
        controller: textEditingController,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12,
        ),
        keyboardType: keyboardType,
        inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                width: 1.2,
                color: Colors.black26,
              ),
            ),
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                width: 1.2,
                color: Colors.black26,
            )),
            isDense: true,
            isCollapsed: true,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.1)),onChanged:onChanged ,),
    );

  }
}
```